# Как написать хороший README?

Tags: документация

Я думаю, каждый видел README-файлы. Хотелось бы получить подробное руководство о том, как написать исключительный README и при этом потратить как можно меньше сил.

- Что такое "файл README"?
- Что мне написать в нем?
- Каким образом я должен отформатировать его?

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304863/how-to-write-a-good-readme

Answer (score 6):

**README** должен быть простым и коротким. Хороший README поможет сэкономить время, особенно, если это README для чего-то вроде библиотеки, разбирающей параметры командной строки.

### Вот что он должен включать в себя:

- имена проектов, всех подмодулей и библиотек (иногда они называются 
  по-разному и путают новых пользователей)
- описание каждого проекта, всех подмодулей и библиотек
- 5-строчный сниппет (фрагмент кода) с примером использования (если это библиотека)
- копирайт и информация о лицензии (или ссылка на лицензию)
- инструкция, как найти документацию
- инструкции по установке, настройке и запуску
- инструкция по получению свежих исходников и подробная инструкция по сборке (или быстрый обзор и ссылка на инструкцию по установке)
- список разработчиков или ссылка на файл с описанием авторов
- инструкции по отправке сообщений об ошибках, пожеланий и запросов на изменения, патчей, а также о том как получать анонсы, присоединиться к списку рассылки или к сообществу разработчиков в других формах
- контактная информация (адрес электронной почты, сайт, название компании, адрес и т.д.)
- краткая история изменений, если это обновление или форк другого проекта
- юридическая информация (для криптографического ПО)

У HTTP-сервера Apache простой, но хороший [README](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/trunk/README). Другой хороший пример - [README](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/make.git/tree/README.template) для GNU make, доступный онлайн.

### О форматировании:

придерживаться традиций Unix насколько это возможно, и/или использовать markdown, особенно для проектов на Github, который рендерит README.md в html-файл.

- Только ASCII-символы, если README написан на английском языке
- пишите его на английском языке, если это возможно, и добавляйте файл с переведенной версией. Добавляйте к такому файлу расширение из двух букв, соответствующее языку, например README.RU
- не более 80 символов в строке
- одна пустая строка между абзацами
- подчеркивайте строку заголовка символами "минус"
- для отступов используйте пробел (0x20), а не табуляцию

### Соберём все вместе...

```
Документация
-------------

GNU make полностью документирован в справочнике по GNU make, который содержится
в этом дистрибутиве как файл make.texinfo. Вы также можете найти он-лайн,
PostScript и DVI версии на сайте FSF. Там же приведена информация о заказе 
документации в печатном виде.

http://www.gnu.org/
http://www.gnu.org/doc/doc.html
http://www.gnu.org/manual/manual.html
```

---

[**Википедия**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/README) определяет README так:

> Файл README (или READ ME), содержит информацию о файлах в папке или
>   архиве и обычно распространяется с ПО.

Википедия перечисляет части README:

> - инструкции по настройке
> - инструкции по установке
> - инструкции по эксплуатации
> - файл манифеста
> - информация об авторских правах и лицензировании
> - контактная информация для дистрибьютора или разработчиков
> - известные ошибки
> - устранение неполадок
> - сведения об авторах и благодарности
> - список изменений