# Правильно ли писать в README.md описания методов?

Tags: java, github, документация

Есть [README.md](https://github.com/ATumbler/VerticalHorizontalScrollView/blob/master/README.md). Как лучше оформить описание методов? Мне кажется, что сейчас неправильно.

> ## VerticalHorizontalScrollView
>
> I did not find the `ScrollView` with two scrolls and decided to write it myself :D I present VerticalHorizontalScrollView - ScrollView with both scroll directions and little customization!
>
> ## scrollTo (int x, int y)
>
> Scroll container to X and Y axis without smooth animation
>
> ## smoothScrollTo (int x, int y)
>
> Scroll container to X and Y axis with smooth animation and default speed
>
> ## smoothScrollTo (int x, int y, int speed)
>
> Scroll container to X and Y axis with smooth animation and animation duration (ms)
>
> ## setOnScrollListener (OnScrollListener listener)
>
> Set listener for scroll action
>
> ## OnScrollListener.onScroll (int x, int y)
>
> Current X and Y axis scroll position

Comment: Код должен быть непосредственно в вопросе.

Comment: Надо бы вам как-нибудь зафигачить документацию в GH Pages. )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Описание методов

Вы вообще не должны документировать методы и классы в readme.

Для этой задачи существуют javadoc-комментарии в коде. Такие комментарии в том числе показываются в среде разработки, что гораздо удобнее, чем заглядывать в ридми.

Даже дублировать комментарии из кода в ридми *вручную* не нужно, потому что вы создадите себе лишнюю работу и неизбежно будете обновлять эти комментарии с задержкой.

Как ещё можно и нужно улучить эти комментарии:

- Опишите принимаемые параметры с помощью `@param x ...`
- Опишите возвращаемое значение с помощью `@return ...`
- Опишите предусловия метода, когда они важны: когда можно вызывать метод, когда нельзя, что необходимо сделать перед этим. Например, что будет, если вызвать `smoothScroll` в то время, как ещё не закончился другой `smoothScroll`?
- Опишите постусловия метода: что получится в результате.

Пример:

```
/**
 * Scroll container to X and Y axis without smooth animation
 * 
 * @param x horizontal coordinate, [0..screen width]
 * @param y vertical coordinate, [0..screen height]
 */
public void scrollTo(
        final int x,
        final int y) {
    // code here
}
```

## Создаём документацию из кода

В Java есть стандартный инструмент — Javadoc. Он может создавать статические веб-страницы с документацией по коду Java. Эти страницы вы можете деплоить на GitHub Pages вручную или с помощью сервера непрерывной интеграции. Можете использовать облачный сервер Travis, он бесплатен для opensource-проектов.

## Что делать с Readme?

Там должны быть совсем другие вещи: описание проекта, лицензия, инструкция по тому, как добавить библиотеку в свой проект.

Подробнее: [Как написать хороший README?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/646965/181472)

## Пара советов по code-style для markdown

- Ставьте пустую строку после заголовков
- Объединяйте тематические блоки под одним заголовком и внутри него используйте заголовки на уровень ниже:

  ```
  # Methods

  ## scrollTo

  ## smoothScrollTo

  # License
  ```
- Каждое предложение в абзаце начинайте с новой строки.
  Можно ещё больше дробить предложения, желательно так, чтобы длина строки была не больше сотни символов.

Comment: Огромное спасибо :)

Answer (score 1):

**Method name**

```
 // description

 { codeblock }
```

Мне кажется будет самое то, если ещё подключить HighlighterJS или ему подобные.

Ещё вариант

```
# Global Method
## Method1
//description
{ codeblock } 
## Method2
```

Comment: А что за `codeboock`, как это работает?

Comment: `code block` имелось в виду?

Comment: Это сам код. Вы можете посмотреть пример по оформлению документации здесь > pointjs.ru/document/#BaseObject , правда у них там что-то с кодировкой случилось, и еще там и не .md